# python project with different subfolder

Tags: python

Hello I have a python application which is structured in this way.

```
--project
    --a_subfolder
        --a_file.py
    --another_subfolder
        --another_file
```

Is there a clean solution to handle dependencies between those files? And is it really good practice to do stuff like that:

```
import a_file
x = a_file.AClass()
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. You mention dependencies between the files but then don't say in which file you are importing `a_file` (I assume you mean to import `a_file` in `another_file`)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
from a_subfolder import a_file as afile
from another_subfolder import another_file as another
```

`x = afile.AClass()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: yes how could a_file import something from another_file?

Comment: In general it is preferable to use absolute imports rather than relative imports. As such you should say `from project.another_subfolder import another_file`

Comment: Thanks, but I think this would only work, if a_file and another_file are in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after comment from Ced**

It sounds like you are working on a large Django project, if that's the case then you are correct to do what you suggest. Put your models in one folder and views in another.

In fact, in a large Django project I have I use this method of organising files; like this example:

```
+-project
|
+--models
   +--__init.py__
   +--cars.py   [car, van & truck classes]
   +--boats.py  [boat & ship classes]
```

Import the classes you want to expose from each sub folder in the `__init.py__` file of the `models` folder.

**Models init.py**

```
from cars import car, van, truck
from boats import boat, ship
```

In your `views` you can then reference the boat and car models with a shorter notation

```
from project.models import car, truck, ship
```

So the meandering answer to your question is yes, you can organise files in separate folders and then reference between them.

Comment: If I'am creating a larger Project with many files it would be much more structed to have different folder. One example would be having a folder for your models, your views and your controllers, so a view would have a controller as dependency and a controller would have some models as depencies

Comment: This was actually my first attempt, but this will only work, if the parent directory of project is in the pythonpath